# How to remove items with whitespace in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have a list consisting of items, where some items only have one whitespace, which i want to delete entirely. How is this exactly done efficiently?

```
aList = [u'This is a test', u' ', u'Something', u' ', u'Something more', u' ', u'Another test', u' ', u' Test test']
```

So all the items with `u' '` has to be removed from the list entirely.

Comment: For your example `lst[::2]` will do it.

Comment: And in general, `lst = [element for element in lst if element != u' ']` will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension with `string.strip()`:

```
>>> l = [u'This is a test', u' ', u'Something', u' ', u'Something more', u' ', u'Another test', u' ', u' Test test']
>>> sans_whitespace = [s for s in l if s.strip()]
>>> sans_whitespace
[u'This is a test', u'Something', u'Something more', u'Another test', u' Test test']
```

Comment: A minor point: this will remove empty strings `''` too, not just space strings. (But this may well be what is wanted.)

Comment: @ajcr: yes, good point, if that is a requirement OP should use `isspace()` as per your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is perhaps to use list comprehension to filter out the strings with only spaces in.

You can check if a string consists entirely of one or more spaces with [`isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace):

```
>>> [x for x in aList if not x.isspace()]
['This is a test', 'Something', 'Something more', 'Another test', ' Test test']
```

Answer (score 0):

result=np.char.replace(result," ","io")

result=np.char.replace(result,"io","")

Comment: If you want to remove all the space you need to replace space with some unique text in the array and then replace the space with empty string like  this one "" and it will be removed. From Gyalpozhing College of Information Technology(GCIT)

Comment: Please [edit] that explanation into the question so that it is not a code-only solution anymore. Also please have a look at [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and take the [tour].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).